# How to apply filter of 'date and time' attribute in rapid miner

Tags: rapidminer

I have one attribute named ‘rental time’ contain 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012 years of data sets of this format like “Mon Jan 14 07:32:30 CET 2008”. I want to apply filter for exclude 2008 and 2009 data. How should I apply filter in rapid miner to exclude this data.

I would be grateful to you.

Kind regards,
Sohaib

Answer (score 2):

You could parse the date attribute using the function `date_str_custom` within the `Generate Attributes` operator to make a new attribute called `year`. It would look like this

```
year = date_str_custom(dateAttribute, "yyyy")
```

From there, you could use the `Filter Examples` operator to exclude examples where `year` is 2008 and 2009. The newly released version 6 has some enhancements to this operator to allow this filtering to be done easily. [Edit] - the RapidMiner forum mentions using this operator directly on the dateTime attribute - so it's even easier - no attribute needs to be generated.

You could refer to this blog [entry](http://rapidminernotes.blogspot.com/2013/05/finding-next-sunday.html) for some more background.